# Choose file name depend on parameter in command line running pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I have a project with structure the same as this:
https://github.com/RomanBaggins/Test_automatisation_final_project.
In conftest.py i get parameters from cmd.
In one of the functions in mane_page.py I need to assign a value(= parameter in cmd) to a variable.
For example:

> cmd:  pytest -s -v --language=en --status=empty test_main_page.py

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--language', action='store', default=None, help="Choose language")
    parser.addoption('--status', action='store', default=None, help="Choose status")



@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def browser(request):
    user_language = request.config.getoption("language")
    if user_language:
        options = Options()
        options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': user_language})
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        browser.implicitly_wait(5)
        yield browser
    else:
        raise pytest.UsageError("--choose your language again")
    browser.quit()

@pytest.fixture
def choose_status(request):
    return request.config.getoption("status")
```

> Then in main_page.py I want to do this:

```
from .base_page import BasePage
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from .locators import MainPageLocators

class MainPage(BasePage): 
    def go_to_login_page(self):
        login_link = self.browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#login_link")
        login_link.click()
        **chosen status = status** <-----------
        def should_be_login_link(self):
        assert self.is_element_present(*MainPageLocators.LOGIN_LINK)
```

> Finally I need this result: chosen_satus = "empty"

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final code, that solve my problem:
conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def choose_status(request):
    return request.config.getoption("status")


def test_main_page(choose_status):
    MainPage().go_to_login_page(choose_status)
```

In main_page.py

```
class MainPage(BasePage): 
    def go_to_login_page(self,choose_status):
        if choose_status == "clear":
            #do smth
```

In test_main_page:

```
def test_guest_can_go_to_login_page(browser,choose_status):
    link = "someurl"

    page = MainPage(browser, link)   
    page.open()                      
    page.go_to_login_page(choose_status)   
    page.should_be_login_link()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send it as a parameter to `go_to_login_page()` from the test

```
@pytest.fixture
def choose_status(request):
    return request.config.getoption("status")

def test_main_page(choose_status):
    MainPage().go_to_login_page(choose_status)


class MainPage(BasePage): 
    def go_to_login_page(self, status):
        # status = empty
```

Comment: I tried and got:
TypeError: go_to_login_page() missing 1 required positional argument: 'status'

Comment: @Roman You need to add parameter to `go_to_login_page(self, status)`

Comment: Maybe I did't understand, but here is my code: https://pastebin.com/j4a3WaQC

Comment: @Roman I'm at work, I can't open this currently. What is your `go_to_login_page()` 
function signature? `go_to_login_page(self)` or `go_to_login_page(self, status)`?

Comment: def go_to_login_page(self, status)

Comment: @Roman And you call it with `choose_status`? `MainPage().go_to_login_page(choose_status)`

Comment: `MainPage().go_to_login_page(status) ; def go_to_login_page(self,status):`
I tried `MainPage().go_to_login_page(choose_status)` but result was the same: in test_main_page.py  `go_to_login_page() missing 1 required positional argument: 'status' `

Comment: @Roman make sure you are running the correct file. You are still using `pytest_addoption` right?

Comment: Yes I'm still using pytest_addoption, that's how I'm running the test : pytest -s -v --language=en --status=empty test_main_page.py

Comment: What is 'status' in your code? MainPage().go_to_login_page(status)

Comment: @Roman It should be `choose_status`, not `status`. The test's parameter (the same name as the `fixture`). The error is on this line? Or in another place you call `go_to_login_page`?

Comment: this is main_page.py code: https://pastebin.com/ht7THPmB and this is test_main_page.py: https://pastebin.com/4tJUBdGS. What do you mean _The test's parameter (the same name as the fixture)._? I also have parameter `language` and fixture `browser` and it works...

Comment: in  test_main_page.py?

Comment: I changed code: https://pastebin.com/1kpY5AEK and got this error: `fixture 'choose_status' not found`